# Does PySpark ML LogisticRegression weightCol implement a sampleWeight or classWeight?

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm defining a binary LogisticRegression pipeline in PySpark ML for a largely imbaalnced dataset.

```
lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.001, weightCol="weight")
```

The API contains an option for weightCol='weight', which I want to use for my imbalanced dataset. The docs for Pyspark 2.3.0.

> weightCol = Param(parent='undefined', name='weightCol', doc='weight column name. If this is not set or empty, we treat all instance weights as 1.0.')

Yes, very verbose...

Is this a sample weight, or a class weight?

I cannot find any information on this elsewhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

When the Spark documentation is vague, especially on the Python side, often your best bet is to go to the *Scala* source code:
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/992447fb30ee9ebb3cf794f2d06f4d63a2d792db/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/LogisticRegression.scala#L491

Without digging too much here, it looks like the weight is a `Double` column applied at the row-level, so I'm going with *sample* weight.